# Swiper Slider not Treating Each Item as Separate Slide in a Horizontal Navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I am encountering an issue while implementing a horizontal navigation slider using Swiper Slider (version 10.2.0) in my React project. My goal is to create a horizontal slider where each item is treated as a separate slide, and the number of items displayed at a time is dependent on the available screen space. The items should be horizontally aligned, and users should be able to slide through items not visible on the screen initially by dragging their mouse or using their thumb (on touch devices).

Currently, all the items are wrapped within a single  with the class swiper-wrapper, which causes them to be treated as one large slide instead of separate slides. This causes a vertical alignment instead of the desired horizontal alignment.

Here is a snippet of the problematic code and the DOM structure:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
    import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
    
    const navItems = [
      { label: 'Item 1', icon: <Icon1 />, link: '#item1' },
      { label: 'Item 2', icon: <Icon2 />, link: '#item2' },
      // ... other items
    ];
    
    export function MainNavigation() {
      return (
        <Swiper
          slidesPerView={'auto'}
          spaceBetween={16}
          grabCursor={true}
          className="md:mx-auto"
        >
          {navItems.map((item, index) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={index} className="flex flex-col items-center gap-y-2 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100">
              <a href={item.link} className="text-center">
                {item.icon}
                <div>{item.label}</div>
              </a>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      );
    }

DOM Structure:

<div class="swiper swiper-initialized swiper-horizontal swiper-ios swiper-backface-hidden flex-row whitespace-nowrap overflow-x-scroll md:mx-auto md:overflow-visible">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="cursor: grab; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="swiper-slide flex flex-col items-center gap-y-2 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 swiper-slide-active" style="margin-right: 16px;">
      <!-- Item 1 details here -->
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide flex flex-col items-center gap-y-2 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 swiper-slide-next" style="margin-right: 16px;">
      <!-- Item 2 details here -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... other items -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried adjusting various Swiper and SwiperSlide properties, but the issue persists. I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to get each item to be recognized as a separate slide and displayed horizontally.

Thank you!